# Data Ingestion - Massively Parallel processing with Concurrency

Tags: concurrency, apache-nifi, esb, nodejs-stream

I am looking for a massively parallel processing system with concurrency which can provide seamless data ingestion solution for over a million IoT devices per 500 milli seconds.

Looking for open source highly scalable rich libraries of different protocol support ESB and can manage multithreading without any failure.

Is Apache Beam, Apache Nifi or Apache Camel or WSO2 better choice.

Comment: Questions asking to recommend software are off-topic. Please use https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite ingestion solution would be Apache NiFi. Let me just mention a few points that seem to cover what you are looking for:

**Richness:** At time of writing NiFi has about 280 processors that ship with it out of the box, allowing you to easiliy work with many data sources

**Scalability:** NiFi has been proven to work with hundereds of nodes in parallel, allowing for huge data volumes and massive events per second

**Open source:** NiFi is 100% open source

Full disclosure: I have not worked with the other solutions you mention, and am an employee of Cloudera, the driving force behind NiFi.